# Layout with weight and min height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm working on a radio app with a simple UI (y-order):

- cover
- title + artist
- buttons play/pause/...
- soundbar

But i'm facing a problem with screens size.

The cover needs to stay at the top, and keep 1:1 ratio (if room).
The soundbar stays at the bottom.

The part with track's info and play/pause button need to resize itself to take the remaining space and center the content in it.

I achieve this by using LinearLayout with a weight of 1 for the middle layout **but on small screen, the content is cropped**.

I try multiple solution (Coordinator, Relative, ...) but no one worked as expected.

When my content isn't cropped, it's aligned bottom instead of being center.

Here's my actual XML that works as expected on normal and big screens but cropped *android:id="@+id/content"* on small screens.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_cover"
        layout="@layout/layout_cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout_informations"
            layout="@layout/layout_informations"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/layout_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_actionbar_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_margin" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_soundbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_soundbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Fab

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the output

Comment: http://hpics.li/a318fff

Comment: The cover (green stripes) need to crop itself if there's not enough space (1:1 originally). The information/buttons part (green brackets) need to center itself in the remaining space between the cover and the soundbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Option 1**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_black_24dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <!--Title play pause-->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <!--Soundbar-->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Album image will take the maximum possible space. If the screen size is small then the album image will be cropped.

**Option 2**

Wrap the `ImageView` within a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.538"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <!--Title play pause-->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <!--Soundbar-->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this case the `ImageView` will always maintain the 1:1 ratio and will get smaller if enough space is not provided.